# Изменение яркости монитора в связке python и nvapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

Идея такова, в зависимости от времени менять яркость одного монитора на приемлимую для глаза.
Перелазил весь интернет, вообще ничего не нашел, кроме как совета "Сделай обертку на C".
Из того что я пробовал:
**1:**

```py
import ctypes
nvapi = ctypes.WinDLL('nvapi.dll')
nvapi.NvAPI_Initialize()
result = nvapi.NvAPI_GetDisplayBrightness(ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.pointer(brightness_value))
nvapi.NvAPI_Unload()
```

Получал ошибку что такой функции нету
**2:**
Пытался разобраться как [здесь](https://github.com/JustAMan/pynvraw/blob/main/src/pynvraw/nvapi_api.py) обращаются к nvapi, все равно ничего не понял

Основная проблема, как я понял, это то, что это статическая обертка, которая уже обращается к другим функциям, именно поэтому ctypes не может обратиться к ним. Можно ли как то это обойти и вообще возможно ли? Желательно с примерами кода)

UPD1:
Вариант с изменением яркости через Windows и powershell не работает, т.к это условное "дергание ползунка" в панели уведомлений. Перебрал много библиотек и ни одна не сработала, пробовал чисто с надеждой на успех, а не со здравым смыслом. У меня этого ползунка попросту нету, и именно поэтому у меня есть два пути, изменение яркости на самом мониторе, что невозможно автоматизировать, и изменение яркости/контрастности/гаммы через панель управления NVidia.

UPD2:
Я не уверен что это можно реализовать именно через nvapi, поэтому возможно имеются другие библиотеки для редактирования фактически переменных драйвера. Написать макрос для изменения ползунков в панели управления NVidia тоже не оптимальный вариант и весьма костыльный и долгий, тем более если пк в момент изменения яркости будет напрямую использоваться

Comment: В общем кое к чему после тестов я пришёл, но заставить менять яркость я так и не смог, в основном я использовал код с гитхаба (ссылку на который вы предоставили), если интересует наработки свои  я предоставлю в виде ответа, но на многое не расчитывайте)

Comment: Был бы очень признателен)